# Rails import from Excel issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, import, ole

We are using Ruby on Rails code to import the data from an Excel sheet, we use an alert where it asks whether we upload the data and append to existing data (MySQL database) and display it in a grid designed in Flex 3, or replace the old data with new data. But we are getting this error:

```
Error in Importing excel files Open
OLE error code:800A03EC in Microsoft Office Excel
Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class
HRESULT error code:0x80020009
```

Comment: What is the code that generates this error?

Comment: it seems that the excel activexobject has some limitations when run from a service, I have the same problem when I try to run a groovy script launched from php on my apache web server.When I launch the script from the command line it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this has nothing to do with rails.
It is more likely a VBA bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of permissions/identities.

I searched on many forums and finally I was able to find a workaround!

In "Components services” => “Computers” => “My Computer” => right-click on “Application Microsoft Excel" then click Properties; in the "Identity" tab, set the user to "Interactive user".

I'm not an expert on this matter so I'm not 100% sure this won't cause any other problem.